# JSOUP Change Selection for Tabs

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup, onchange

I am trying to select the timeframe in a set of tabs.  and have the page refresh with the results of the new timeframe, but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is the HTML for the set of tabs. The default when you load the page is Hourly.  I need to change the values to the Monthly.

```
 <div id="technicalstudiesSubTabs">
    <ul class="tabsBoxSubMenu techStudiesTabsSubMenu  innerPage "      id="timePeriodsWidget"  data-view="normal">
        <li pairid="1" data-period="60" class="first"><a href="javascript:void(0);">1 min.</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="300" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">5 mins</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="900" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">15 mins</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="1800" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">30 mins</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="3600" class="selected "><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hourly</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="18000" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">5 Hours</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="86400" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">Daily</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="week" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">Weekly</a></li>
        <li pairid="1" data-period="month" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">Monthly</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Once the values for the monthly are available, I can then parse the information that I need.

Thanks in advance!!
Eddi Rae

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup does not run JavaScript. So you can't do it the way you imagine.

you got two possibilities:

1) Use something like Selenium, which in fact drives a real browser which will do JavaScript and you can access it via Java. This is however slow and introduces new dependencies to your project.

2) Try to identify the actual calls that are made to to the back end when you press the button. So identify what the JavaScript is actually doing. You need to use the browser developer's tools for this. If you are successful and find the AJAX calls that will set your site to "hourly", then you can mimic those via JSoup.

Comment: I think I would prefer option two.  I have never done this before.  Do you have a link with a good example that I can read so I can learn how to work it?

Comment: Sorry, don't have tutorials at hand for this one. But there should be tons of info out there about how to use the browser's development tools.